# Android Bitmap Recycle With Lollipop

Tags: android, bitmap, recycle

my code did work before Lollipop update. But now, since lollipop recycle bitmap by itself my app crashes and I take this error;

```
Process: com.package.example, PID: 16356
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
            at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1224)
            at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1280)
            at com.kafyazilim.cocacola.Fragment.TopluFragment.getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(TopluFragment.java:87)
            at com.kafyazilim.cocacola.Fragment.TopluFragment$1.onClick(TopluFragment.java:114)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

and this is my code:

```
public static Bitmap getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(ListView listview, Activity activity)
    {
        Bitmap bmp;
        ListAdapter adapter  = listview.getAdapter();
        int itemscount       = adapter.getCount();
        int allitemsheight   = 0;
        List<Bitmap> bmps    = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {
            View childView      = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
            childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
            childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            childView.buildDrawingCache();
            bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());

            allitemsheight+=childView.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        Bitmap bigbitmap    = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas bigcanvas    = new Canvas(bigbitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int iHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
            bmp = bmps.get(i);
            bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
            iHeight+=bmp.getHeight();


            bmp.recycle();
            bmp = null;

        }
        return bigbitmap;
    }
```

What can I do to solve this issue ? Thanks for advice.

Comment: Simply, one of the bmps is null.

Comment: That's the point. But even all bmps's are not null before Lollipop, some of bmps's are null on Lollipop version, I wonder why.

Comment: read the javadocs of `View#setDrawingCacheEnabled`

Comment: Maybe bitmaps are recycled and made null more agressively in more recent versions of Android?

Comment: I already used setDrawingCacheEnabled(true), still don't have the answer.

Comment: did you read the javadocs of `View#setDrawingCacheEnabled` ?

Comment: Yes, i already used them.

Comment: and did you try the soft layer?

Comment: "When hardware acceleration is turned on, enabling the drawing cache has no effect on rendering because the system uses a different mechanism for acceleration which ignores the flag." But hardware acceleration is already turned off. Am i missing a thing ? Sorry I'm so confused right now.

Comment: how do you know the hardware accel is turned off?

Comment: android:hardwareAccelerated="false" isn't that enough or did I miss anything again ?

Comment: i dont know, try: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#determining

Comment: It returns me false.

Comment: so you have bad luck ;-(